# Weak and weak* sequential convergence of measures, Grothendieck space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Consider the space $M_b(X, \Sigma)$ of bounded $\Sigma$-measurable functions equipped with the supremum norm. Then $M_b(X, \Sigma)' = ba(\Sigma)$ is the space of finitely additive signed measures on $\Sigma$ with bounded variation. Denote by $ca(\Sigma) \subseteq ba(\Sigma)$ the subspace of countably additive measures. On the Banach space $ca(\Sigma)$ consider the weak topology (relative to $ca(\Sigma)'$) and the weak$^*$ topology relative to $M_b(X, \Sigma)$. Then weak convergence implies weak$^*$-convergence. However, it seems to me that sequential convergence in $ca(\Sigma)$ coincides for the weak and weak$^*$ topologies:

- Weak$^*$-convergence $\mu_n \to^* \mu$ means $\mu_n f \to \mu f$ for all $f \in M_b(X, \Sigma)$
- For weak convergence, it is known that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly if and only if $\mu_n(B) \to \mu(B)$ for all $B \in \Sigma$ [Dunford-Schwartz, "Linear Operators", IV.9.5].

So, by choosing $f = \chi_B \in M_b(X, \Sigma)$ we get $\mu_n \to^* \mu$ implies   $\mu_n \to \mu$.

Is this somehow related to the notion of a Grothendieck space? A Banach space $E$ is called a [Grothendieck space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_space) if in $E'$ weak$^*$-convergence for sequences implies weak convergence (so that they then coincide).